# How to add an EditText in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to add an `EditText` within a `TextView`. My idea is to build a two activities, wherein in the first activity, fill in the blanks type of question will be entered in `EditText` and will be sent to second activity on button click and in second activity I want the text entered in the first activity to be displayed along with the `EditText` in the place of blank where it needs to answered.

My whole idea was to enter fill in the blank question with underscore at the place to be answered in the first activity and to display the question in the second activity by replacing the underscore with `EditText`.

first activity class code:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view)
    {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.button)
        {
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            String text = editText.getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("mytext", text);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    }

}
```

First activity layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".FirstActivity">


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="Enter here"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Second Activity Class:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        TextView textview1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        int positionX = textview1.getLeft();
        int positionY = textview1.getRight();

        EditText ed = new EditText(this);
        ed.setEnabled(false);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ed.getLayoutParams();
        params.leftMargin = positionX;
        params.topMargin = positionY;
        params.width = 30;
        ed.setLayoutParams(params);

        textview1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("mytext"));

    }

}
```

Second Activity Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why you use edit text in second activity, you simply use text view to display text.

Comment: Thanks reply, along with the display of the text entered in the first activity in second activity, I want user to answer the fill in the blank with _ replaced by edittext.

Comment: To do this you don't "add" an EditText into a TextView, I think the easiest way to achieve this is to create so many TextViews as characters has the word and instead of TextView you put an EditText where the user has to make his input.

Another way is to create your custom View extending an EditText or TextView, or even creating it from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You could split your text with your underscore characters, then, programmatically add TextViews and EditText.

Take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).